# Checkbox symbols wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, symbols

I am having a problem with the tutorial of codelearn 
[See here](http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/3/Introducing-forms,-migrations-&-ajax-in-Rails/2/Rails-migration,-form_for-&-checkboxes)

I have a form

```
<%= form_for :complete, :url => "/todos/complete", :method => :post do |f| %>
  <% @todo_items.each do |t| %>
    <%= f.check_box :todo_ids[], t.id %>
    <%= t.todo_item %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Complete todos", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>`
```

I've got a problem with the symbol todo_ids[]. I get the error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)" at the line where it is written.
I tried another way with form_tag but that does not change a thing, I still get the error.

What I don't understand is that they don't have this problem in the tutorial. 
Please do you have any idea ?

Many thanks